# C#, new Bitmap with IntPtr, ArgumentException

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap

I have a very strange issue.

Here is a simplified code of mine to explain :

```
class Bitmap1
{
    public Bitmap nImage;
    public IntPtr data;


    public Bitmap1()
    {
        int w = 2450;
        int h = 2450;

        this.data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(w*h);

        nImage = new Bitmap(w, h, w, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, data);

    }
}
```

When `w` and `h` are equal to **2448**, everything works well if  I invocate the constructor.

But when h and w are equal to **2450**, I have an `ArgumentException` which seems launch by the "new Bitmap(...);"

I can't understand, and the documentation doesn't say there is a limited size for `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

What's wrong? Are there other ways to do what I want ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When a function throws an exception indicating that you violated its contract then reading its documentation is a good idea.

Comment: Actually, i was reading it for hours ! But I was focused on my IntPtr, and haven't seen the multiple of 4 stride !!! Sorry

Comment: A yes, that kind of selective reading happens from time to time.

Comment: Thanks forsvarir for editing my post ! The layout is much better now ! I'll try to do as well as you next time I have a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> stride 
>   Type: System.Int32
>   Integer that specifies the byte offset between the beginning of one scan line and the next. This is usually (but not necessarily) the number of bytes in the pixel format (for example, 2 for 16 bits per pixel) multiplied by the width of the bitmap. **The value passed to this parameter must be a multiple of four**..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx

So you need something like the following:

```
int w = 2450;
int h = 2450;
int s = 2452;//Next multiple of 4 after w

this.data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(s*h);

nImage = new Bitmap(w, h, s, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, data);
```

This means there are 2 bytes between every line that are just padding and not part of the bitmap itself. When doing pointer arithmetic you obviously need to do `s*y+x` and not `w*y+x` to account for the padding.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("SomeImage");

// Lock the bitmap's bits.  
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The previous answer said the stride must be a multiple of 4, so when I manipulate my byte array, I must be aware of that 2 bytes on each lines.

With your solution, is there the same offset in the array which is brought by the stride ?